# Batch file rename with substitution lookup

Tags: bash, rename

Using bash, how I can batch rename a large number of files, where I need to construct a new name for each file, based on its existing name and a 'contextual map' - don't know what else to call it – of name fragments.

I have a lot of files in like this:

```
001.jpg
003.jpg
004.jpg
007.jpg
...
```

and a map like this:

```
001,white
003,grey
004,red
007,green
...
```

And now I want to rename all files, so that 001.jpg becomes 001-white.jpg etc..

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

bash4: First read the mappings into an array

```
declare -A arr2
while IFS=, read -r -a arr; do
    arr2[${arr[0]}]="${arr[1]}";
done < mapfile.txt
```

And then rename

```
for f in [0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg; do
    if [[ "${arr2[${f%.*}]+_}" ]]
    then
        mv -- "${f}" "${f%.*}"-"${arr2[${f%.*}]}"."${f##*.}";
    else
        mv -- "${f}" "${f%.*}"-default."${f##*.}";
    fi
 done
```

Comment: Will work in `zsh` but not in `bash` or `ksh93` where numbers with a leading 0 are considered as octal.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, i tested this on `GNU bash, version 4.2.25` before posting, it works. I am guessing this is because `arr2` is considered an associative array by default under bash 4 so the index is not considered an "arithmetic context"?

Comment: If a file isn't in the map, it's renamed to e.g. `042-.jpg`. You may want to add a test for this.

Comment: @1_CR, have you tested with `008` in the mapfile?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, ah I see what you mean. I seem to be able to work around this by explicitly declaring `arr2` an associative array. Tagging this a bash4 solution

Answer (score 2):

You can simply execute

```
join -t. -j1 <(tr , . < map) filelist | sed 's/\./-/' | paste filelist - | xargs -L1 mv
```

where `map` is the contextual map and `filelist` is the list of files. The join will split on `.` and uses the first field as a join value; both lists must be sorted.  `paste` will then glue each line of `filelist` with the newly generated  filename together in one line, while `xargs` then calls `mv` on each of those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
for file in [0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg;do
    name="${file%%.*}" # Remove extension
    map="$(grep "$name" map_file | cut -d',' -f 2)"
    echo mv "$file" "$name-$map".jpg
done
```

This assumes the "map" is in the file `map_file`. In recent versions of Bash, you can also transform this file into an associative array and use that for convenience (instead of going through the `map_file` for each new file you want to rename).

By the way, this will only `echo` the `mv` commands. Remove the `echo` when you feel that everything is in order to actually do the renaming.

Answer (score 1):

```
< map sed 's/\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/mv -- "\1.jpg" "\1-\2.jpg"/' | sh -x
```

(that assumes the map file doesn't contain `"`, `$`, backslash or backtick characters.

Comment: this looks interesting, very terse, can you explain how this works?

Comment: If the map mentions a non-existent file, you'll get an error message, which is likely not desired.